# UILabel Not Released And Wrong Position Display

Tags: core-animation, position, uilabel, hide, release

What I am trying to do is display a label on loading view for first time. When User will tap an object, that label should disappear and three circles should appear on its position. But what is happening is that *my label is not hidden when I am trying to release it*, as I will be needing it no more. Also it is not *present at position* I want.

[image: View After Being Load And Tapped]

What I have done is:

```cs
@interface AnimateCircle : UIViewController
{
UILabel *text;
CALayer *smallCircle1;
CALayer *smallCircle2;
CALayer *smallCircle3;
}
```

and then declared property for label and synthesized it. **Please note that I have added** `AnimateCircle` **as subview of a view. So my subview is starting from small circles as indicated in 2nd figure.**

In `viewDidLoad`, I wrote:

```cs
text = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 310, 100)];
text.text = @"Tap the Red Button To Start The Timer...!";
text.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@'SnellRoundHand-Bold" size:8];

[self.view addSubview:text];
[text release];
```

At tap Gesture, I call a method in which I release my label `text` to hide it.

```cs
[text removeFromSuperView];
```

and draw three circles at its position. Just showing position...

```cs
smallCircle1.frame = CGRectMake(100, 15, 30, 30);
smallCircle2.frame = CGRectMake(140, 15, 30, 30);
smallCircle3.frame = CGRectMake(180, 15, 30, 30);
```

Failed after struggling for 2 hours. Please can someone tell me that what am I missing? Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

You must actually add the 3 circles to the view.

Use  `self.view.layer addSublayer:`.

Comment: I have already done this, thats why I can see them on screen :)

Comment: Ok, got it. Sorry, I figured that was a simulation that you had put together to illustrate your goal. So what is the specific problem you're encountering?

Comment: UILabel 'text' is not hidden when I release it on user tap. And also it is not displaying on position I want i.e. `text.frame = CGRectMake(10, 5, 310, 100);`